# WSO2 IS - How to get custom claims from WSO2 Identity Server via user-info rest service

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to get custom claims from Identity Server via user-info service in WSO2 Identity Server Version 5.3.0.

This is the invocation to the user-info service:

```
GET https://host:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid HTTP/1.1
```

And the response only contains the subject info:

```
{
  "sub": "user@carbon.super"
}
```

How can I get all the claims of the user via user-info service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add custom claims as requested claims in Service Provider configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the claims that should be included in the response. That should be configured in the Claim Configuration of the Service Provider. You can refer (1) for more information.

(1) http://dinukshaish.blogspot.com/2017/02/getting-started-with-oauth-20-using.html